# Find nested key-value pair in yaml

Tags: yq

I'm trying to use yq to find if a key-value pair exists in a yaml.
Here's an example yaml:

```
houseThings:
  - houseThing:
      thingType: chair
  - houseThing:
      thingType: table
  - houseThing:
      thingType: door
```

I just want an expression that evaluates to true (or any value, or exits with zero status) if the key-value pair of `thingType: door` exists in the yaml above.

The best I can do so far is find if the value exists by recursively walking all nodes and checking their value:
`yq eval '.. | select(. == "door")' my_file.yaml` which returns `door`. But I also want to make sure `thingType` is its key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the select statement under `houseThing` as

```sh
yq e '.houseThings[].houseThing | select(.thingType == "door")' yaml
```

or do a recursive look for it

```sh
yq e '.. | select(has("thingType")) | select(.thingType == "door")' yaml
```

Comment: thanks! their doc on `select` needs to be more than just these two specific examples https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/select